# fatal error: Index out of range swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I want to be able to display what the user enters, in a custom cell that i have created. But i am getting this error when i launch my app and then app just crashes every time i open it

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!


    var titleArray: [String] = []
    var whereArray: [String] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArray.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customCell

        cell.title.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.location.text = whereArray[indexPath.row] //getting error here (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)


        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let titleObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "title")
        let whereObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "location")

        if let tempTitle = titleObject as? [String] {
            titleArray = tempTitle
        }


        if let tempWhere = whereObject as? [String] {
            whereArray = tempWhere
        }

        table.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: Clearly you have fewer objects in the `whereArray` than the `tempTitle` array. Your code is assuming they have the same number of objects but they don't.

Comment: Why is your data in two separate arrays instead of a single array?

Comment: @rmaddy both of the arrays would have same amount of objects. technically, when i run the app for the first time, both arrays are empty

Comment: The error indicates that the arrays to do not have the same number of objects. Use the debugger and verify this for yourself.

Comment: @rmaddy you were right. I fixed the problem! I deleted everything from my arrays and started over. Thank you very much! But how would i fix this error for good if someone doesn't enter one of the value and it doesn't get stored in an array?

Comment: @KunjPatel You need to show alert when user enter empty data, also batter if you  use single array of type Dictionary or custom class.

Comment: could you not just add an empty string "" when the user doesn't enter a value.

Comment: Don't use two arrays. Use a single arrays of a struct that has two properties. .